# Can `clip` remove the outer border of this tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I borrowed some code from [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146942/inscribing-multiple-incircles-to-a-triangle-in-tikz) and adapted it very slightly, producing this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


   \begin{scope}
   \clip (0,0) circle (3cm);
   \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
   \end{scope}

   \coordinate (a) at (90:3);
   \coordinate (b) at (-30:3);
   \coordinate (c) at (210:3);
   \foreach \in in {1,2,...,4}
   {
     \node[circle through=(a),draw] {};
     \draw (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
     \coordinate(aux) at (a);
     \path (a)--(b) coordinate[pos=.5] (a);
     \path (b)--(c) coordinate[pos=.5] (b);
     \path (c)--(aux) coordinate[pos=.5] (c);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this result:

[image]

I was hoping to get rid of the outermost circle; hence the scoping and clipping. That didn't work, though. I also tried putting the `clip` command after the `draw` command and adding a `clip` option to the `scope` environment. Is there way to use `clip` to do what I want? (It looks like there's a way to start with the triangle and calculate from there, as in [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273216/instructing-tikz-to-calculate-the-radius-of-a-circle-inscribed-in-a-triangle), but I'm hoping to avoid that level of complication.

Answer (score 1):

This code overwrites nodes and redraws circles. A minimal surgery might be

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}



   \coordinate (a) at (90:3);
   \coordinate (b) at (-30:3);
   \coordinate (c) at (210:3);
   \foreach \in in {1,2,...,4}
   {
     \ifnum\in=1
     \else
     \node[circle through=(a),draw] {};
     \fi
     \draw (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
     \coordinate(aux) at (a);
     \path (a)--(b) coordinate[pos=.5] (a);
     \path (b)--(c) coordinate[pos=.5] (b);
     \path (c)--(aux) coordinate[pos=.5] (c);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: cercles]

In the loop, the circle is drawn first, *(at the beginning of the loop)* then the point `(a)` is redefined with `\coordinate(aux) at (a);`, so it is enough to draw the circle at the end of the loop and not at the beginning.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

   \begin{scope}
   \clip (0,0) circle (3cm);
   %\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
   \end{scope}

   \coordinate (a) at (90:3);
   \coordinate (b) at (-30:3);
   \coordinate (c) at (210:3);
   \foreach \in in {1,2,...,4}
   {
     %\node[circle through=(a),draw] {};
     \draw (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
     \coordinate(aux) at (a);
     \path (a)--(b) coordinate[pos=.5] (a);
     \path (b)--(c) coordinate[pos=.5] (b);
     \path (c)--(aux) coordinate[pos=.5] (c);
     \node[circle through=(a),draw] {};% draw the circle at the end
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `begin{scope}
   \clip (0,0) circle (3cm);
   \end{scope}`? And there is an additional circle in the center, which is not there in the OP's screen shot, and the reason why my answer as an `\ifnum` in.

Comment: It's in the code of the question and it's useless. Yes, there is an extra circle (in a very small way) let's see if it bothers the OP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the outermost triangle out of the loop
2. reduce the iteration number
3. the loop  starts by calculating the new coordinates (a), (b) and (c)

!

```
   \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

   \coordinate (a) at (90:3);
   \coordinate (b) at (-30:3);
   \coordinate (c) at (210:3);
   \draw(a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;


   \foreach \in in {1,2,...,3}
   {
     \coordinate(aux) at (a);
     \path (a)--(b) coordinate[pos=.5] (a);
     \path (b)--(c) coordinate[pos=.5] (b);
     \path (c)--(aux) coordinate[pos=.5] (c);
     \node[circle through=(a),draw] {};
     \draw (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]